# Convert SQL query in Criteria query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have SQL query:

```
select * from n left join ns on n.id = ns.n_id
where n.public = true and (ns.n_id is null or ns.node_id in ('25','1407114'));
```

n - entity, ns - table of basic types (@ElementCollection), which is the field of this entity.

Here are instances:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<N> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(N.class);
Root<N> news = criteria.from(N.class);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the entities are mapped.

Here's my attempt:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<N> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(N.class);
Root<N> news = criteria.from(N.class);
Join<Object, Object> nsJoin = news.join( "ns", JoinType.LEFT );
Join<Object, Object> nodeJoin = nsJoin.join( "node" );
query.where( builder.and(
        builder.isTrue( news.get( "public" ) ),
        builder.or( nsJoin.isNull(), nodeJoin.get("id" ).in( 25, 1307114 ) )
) );
```

I can give you better answer if you show me the entities

Comment: Thanks for the feedback) I had to change the structure of the entity a lil' bit for solve